# Why might "fetch as Google" be taking longer to index submitted pages than it used to for my site?

Tags: google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, google-index, fetch-as-google

I am not new to webmaster tools. I have long used "fetch as Google" to index my pages within 5 minutes.  I don't know what happened to the index timing, but it is taking much longer now.

Is anyone else also having the same problem or have experienced it before?

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters! The process is different now and has been for quite a while. Fetch as Google or Inspect URL will fetch your page immediately but schedule the regular googlebot to fetch the page usually within 2 days.  The regular googlebot will index your page. I suspect this was done because people were abusing the feature. Cheers!!